# Why should we avoid theming forms with template files?

Tags: forms, theming

The issue was raised in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form). Why not exploit the advantages that template files offer in the case of forms?

Comment: We should **not** avoid this! If you care about the presentation of any particular form, create a tpl for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no good reason for not using a template file to theme a form. As I stated in that question, the simple #prefix and #suffix tricks might not be enough, say if you wanted the entire form to be a table rather than div based. I've used drupal_render with a form element parameter in a template to draw the individual fields in the form, but make sure you call drupal_render without an argument at the end of the template to populate the rest of the form, such as the form hash etc. as it won't validate.