# How to apply a theme function/template to my form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I think `theme_form()` is responsible for rendering forms! I want to change the look of a form, a lot. I think just instead of `theme_form` I can use my custom theme function/template file.

I can use `hook_form_alter` to change any form's structure using my module. Now my question is, how do tell the form to use a theme function/template I've created?

Is there a `#theme` property *(or something like that)* available for forms, which I can set to my theme function/template file?

***P.S.*** I checked out [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form) but I need more explanation, when the case is: I'm trying to theme a form defined by another module/core modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `template.php` of your theme

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks['form_id_of_form'] = array(
    'template' => 'path_to_tpl_file',
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

Also you can try

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'form_id_of_form') {
    $form['#theme'] = 'path_to_tpl_file';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite right. In your hook_theme, you declared the theme callback to be "form_id_of_form". Therefore, the hook_form_alter should implement $form['#theme'] = 'form_id_of_form', not 'path_to_tpl_file'

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a #theme property (or something like that) available for forms, which I can set to my theme function/template file?

Yes there is. Take a look at the [#theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#theme) key in the Form API Reference. Take a look at the code for [theme_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form/7) for the default implementation.