# Add an input[type="file"] label

Tags: theming, forms, 7

i need to style the `input[type="file"]`, the only way to really style them is to add a `<label>` which has the same `for` value as the input's `id`. Drupal does not provide a correct label in single `input[type="file"]` upload and even no label in multiples `input[type="file"]` uploads. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup in Drupal is always overridable.  In this case, you may either need to use a [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module to modify the label html, override the [theme_file()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_file/7) theme function (which is responsible for producing the markup for the file input element), or [theme the form specifically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26169/how-to-apply-a-theme-function-template-to-my-form).  Any of these three methods should be able to meet your needs (although I'm partial to the theme_file() approach).

Comment: Many thanks coreyp, i used the theme_file() theme function. Its works with single and multiple file uploads, just need to add `<label for="' . $element['#attributes']['id'] . '">Text</label>`