# module's local *.tpl.php, defined in $theme_registry, "not found or invalid" when referenced later in module

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I built a custom login module for my Drupal7.26 install.

Extending it, I've added a *.tpl.php locally

```
ls sites/all/modules/custom/jl_login/templates/
    user-login-member-form.tpl.php
```

To get the tpl.php into theme registry, in "my_login_mod.module" I added

```
function jl_login_theme() {
    return array(
        'user_login_member_form' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'template' => 'templates/user-login-member-form',
        )
    );
}
```

After module  disable/uninstall/enable, and clear all caches, I load my site/page.

Checking output with

```
<?php print '<pre>'; var_dump(theme_get_registry()); print '</pre>'; ?>
```

I see the form in the registry

```
 ["user_login_member_form"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["render element"]=>
    string(4) "form"
    ["template"]=>
    string(76) "sites/all/modules/custom/jl_login/templates/user-login-member-form"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "module"
    ["theme path"]=>
    string(43) "sites/all/modules/custom/jl_login"
    ["preprocess functions"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(19) "template_preprocess"
    }
    ["process functions"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "template_process"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "ctools_process"
    }
  }
```

Later in my .module, I use the form:

```
function _jl_login_login_block_view($delta='') {
    $this_user_login_form    = drupal_get_form('user_login_member_form');
    ...
```

But on load I see in drupal logs,

```
Feb 24 16:32:16 dev d7: http://dev.loc|1393288336|php|127.0.0.1|http://dev.loc/||0||Notice: Undefined index: user_login_member_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 771 of /home/jl/d7/includes/form.inc).
Feb 24 16:32:16 dev d7: http://dev.loc|1393288336|php|127.0.0.1|http://dev.loc/||0||Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user_login_member_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 806 of /home/jl/d7/includes/form.inc).
```

What do I need to change to be able to use/reference the local form?

Comment: is it a cut and paste typo that you seem to have `user-login-alt-form.tpl.php` yet referencing `user-login-member-form`, eg `-alt-` vs `-member-`?

Answer (score 2):

[`drupal_get_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) expects the name of a function that builds a form array, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#theme'] = 'user_login_member_form';

  $form['foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Bar'),
    '#default_value' => t('Baz'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_some_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Process $form_state['values']
}

// In a hook...
$form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_some_form');
```

You don't need to add the form function to a registry as such, just giving it the same name as the string you pass to `drupal_get_form()` is enough.

[`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) is for registering theme functions, which is why you're currently getting an error.

The [Form generation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7) docs have a bit more information, and the [FAPI reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) is invaluable if you're new to the form API. For theming the form, there are some excellent answers to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form) which should help.

Comment: Template files aren't synonymous with forms - you can use a template file to _theme_ a form, but you need to use the form API to build the structure

Comment: I've added a bit to the code, is that what you're looking for? It's hard to understand what you're asking, as you say you don't want a form but you're using the `drupal_get_form()` function, which can only use a form. Could you possibly mean `theme('user_login_member_form');`? If so, you need to change `'render element' => 'form'` to `'variables' => array()` in your theme definition, and clear the caches