# Where is theThe Comment Form Template?

Tags: theming, comments

I can find the comments template
at modules/comments/comment.tpl.php

But where is the  comment Form Template please?

I want to add a users image next to the form

Thanks for your help

Charles

Comment: Check [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the default **comment module** , and editing the core options is not a good practice at all.

You can alter the comment  form in your active theme **template.php** or **hook_form_alter()** function in your custom module

```
<?php 
function THEMENAME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
        //dpm($form); //shows original $form array 
        //$form['author']['#type'] = 'fieldset'; 
       // $form['author']['#title'] = 'Your Information'; 
       // $form['author']['#collapsible'] = FALSE; 
      //  $form['your_comment'] = array( '#type' => 'fieldset', '#title' => t('Your Comment'), '#collapsible' => FALSE, '#weight' => 2, ); 
        //Subject 
       // $form['your_comment']['subject'] = $form['subject']; 
       // unset($form['subject']); 
     //   $form['your_comment']['subject']['#weight'] = -10; 
        //Comment 
        $form['your_comment']['comment_body']['#prefix'] = "<div>User picture</div>" ;
        $form['your_comment']['comment_body'] = $form['comment_body']; 


}
?>
```

You can add user picture using prefix/suffix in the comment form.
Try if it work for you.