# Drupal 7 form api > Display part of tree outside tree

Tags: forms

Very hard to explain by title, but this is what I mean:

I have a form which shows packages and their add-ons. A simplified version:

```
foreach ($packages as $package) {
  $form['package_' . $package->nid] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-select package">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['package_' . $package->nid]['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#return_value' => 'package_' . $package->nid,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="package_select">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#tree' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['package_' . $package->nid]['title'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="package_title">',
    '#markup' => $package->title,
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $form['package_' . $package->nid]['addons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="package_addons">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  foreach ($addons as $addon) {
    $form['package_' . $package->nid]['addons']['addon_' . $addon->nid] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="container-select addon'">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['package_' . $package->nid]['addons']['addon_' . $addon->nid]['select'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => array($addon->nid => $addon->title),
      '#return_value' => 'addon_' . $addon->nid,
      '#prefix' => '<div class="addon_select">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['package_' . $package->nid]['addons']['addon_' . $addon->nid]['title'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="addon_title">',
      '#markup' => $addon->title,
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<div class="container-select package">
  <div class="package_select">...</div>
  <div class="package_title">...</div>
  <div class="package_addons">
    <div class="container-select addon">
      <div class="addon_title">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-select addon">
      .. second addon .. and so on ..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-select package">
.. second package .. and so on .. 
</div>
```

The problem is that I want the add-ons to be displayed BELOW the package container it belongs to, but still have the values within the tree. So I want:

```
<div class="container-select package">
  <div class="package_select">...</div>
  <div class="package_title">...</div>
</div>
<div class="package_addons">
  <div class="container-select addon">
    <div class="addon_title">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-select addon">
    .. second addon .. and so on ..
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-select package">
.. second package .. and so on .. 
</div>
```

I thought about doing this with CSS first. But it's getting a mess. Second I thought about using jQuery to move the package_addons element. But actually I hope there is a better solution by Drupal / PHP, so I don't have to mess around with CSS or jQuery.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can provide your own `#theme` function for any FAPI element (including the top level of a tree). http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form contains some useful code maybe that can get you started?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't see how using #theme can change the order of my elements.

Comment: With `#theme` you're building the HTML yourself - the elements will be in whatever order you decide to write them in

Comment: While I couldn't find the right way with using #theme in the first place I found another solution changes the logic within the form itself.

Comment: After having another issue I can finally see how I could have arranged the files differently by using #theme and my own template:

Using this code in your .tpl file helps rendering the fields in the order you want:
`print drupal_render_children($form['specific_field']);
print drupal_render_children($form);`

The 'specific_field' will be rendered first and won't be rendered again while the whole form will be rendered on the second line.