# Template for custom form not working

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I am trying to theme a custom using a template file but unfortunately I am not getting it by using the below method.
listing.module

```
function listing_menu() {
  $items['ad-listing'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'adlist_template',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

  );
      return $items;
    }
function listing_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Title')),
);
$form['category'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
        'default' => '- Category -',
        'Car' => 'Car',
        'Van' => 'Van',
    ),
);
 return $form
}

function listing_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
return array(
  'listing_form' => array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'adlisting',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'listing') . '/form',
  )
    );
}
function adlist_template(){
    return theme('listing_form');
}
```

listing/form/adlisting.tpl.php

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
              <h5 class="">Contact Information</h5>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 large-6 medium-6 columns">
              <?php print render($form['title']); ?>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
              <?php print render($form['category']); ?>
          </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns">
          <?php print render($form['ad_submit']); ?>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to follow this thread [How to a use a template file to theme a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form) but did not help me, neither other solutions

Comment: Why do you want to use a custom template to render a form, I just asking because if all you want is add custom classes or wrapper around form fields, you can pretty much do that with FAPI using 'fieldset'/'container'  for wrappers and '#attributes' for clasess;

Comment: Hey there, try changing the name of `listing_form()` to something like `listing_myform()` and flush your caches. I'm assuming your module is `listing` so by naming your function `listing_form` you are actually implementing `hook_form` which I'm pretty sure you do not want to do.

Comment: @othermachines - Of course he wants to implement `hook_form`. Why not?

Comment: @leymannx AFAIK `hook_form` is a node API hook (if I'm wrong feel free to enlighten me). This function above is a theme function. I honestly don't know if it would even be problematic - since obviously `blah_form` is a popular naming convention - just trying to eliminate possible gotchas.

Comment: Now it dawns on me that of course the node API hook would only be called for node modules, so never mind. @DropDragon So are you getting a 404 or is it something else?

Comment: @othermachines no errors are thrown but I don't see my form rendering, watchdog says the theme listing_form not defined

Comment: @arpitr I will be making my form dynamic, more than how it looks right now, so I wanted the template to handle the classes and wrappers instead of FAPI

Comment: @othermachines Changing the form name to listing  _myform() helped me recognized the template and load it for my hook_menu, though I see my template is what /ad-listing is using, I don't see the form elements being rendered for the code <?php print render($form['category']); ?> any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 major changes on the code above

1. I changed the form name to listing_adform()
2. I changed the hook_menu to call my form not theme

> ```
>   $items['ad-listing'] = array(
>     //'page callback' => 'adlist_template',
>     'access callback' => TRUE,
>     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
>     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
>     'page arguments' => array('listing_adform'),
>   );
> ```

Flushed the cache, and I saw my fields rendering using my template in form/adlisting.tpl.php

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, DropDragon. So it helps others, I would recommend including all of the relevant code in your answer.

Comment: @othermachines - Thank you for your valid objection on `hook_form`. I get your point. Since this is no content type defined here, `hook_form` shouldn't be the naming to be used here. I still wonder, that even on [DO](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390) `hook_form` is used in simple form tutorials.

Comment: @leymannx Yeah, I wonder about that, too. I guess it's just one of those things that you can get away with in some cases, but not in others, and nobody is exactly sure what makes the difference. :)