# form in a .tpl.php file

Tags: nodes

This is the code in my template.php file.

```
function studiga_theme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {    
    $items['add_property_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'node--14',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'studiga_theme') . '/templates/node',
    );

    return $items;
}


 function custom_add_property_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('First name')),
    );
    $form['last_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Last name')),
    );
    $form['address'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Address')),
    );
    $form['city'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('City')),
    );
    $form['state'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            'default' => 'State',
            '...' => '...',
        ),
    );
    $form['zip'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Zip')),
    );
    $form['email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Email')),
    );
    $form['phone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Phone')),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );

    return $form;
}
```

This is the code in node--14.tpl.php.

Contact Information

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns">
        <?php print render($form['submit']); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

But no fields are appearing - what am I doing wrong? You can't have a straight forward  in a tpl.php file can you?

Comment: All I want is a form in a .tpl.php file and to be able to access the fields when they are posted. You can't use <form></form> and no fields show up if I use $items['add_property_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'node--14',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'studiga_theme') . '/templates/node',
    );

Answer (score 2):

Given your definition of `studiga_theme_theme()`, Drupal will never call `custom_add_property_form()` because there isn't any relation between the theme template you define, and that function. Eventually, you could implement the preprocess function for that theme template, and set there a variable that is passed to the template.

```
function studiga_theme_preprocess_add_property_form(&$variables) {
  $variables['form'] = /* define here the form */;
}
```

Now your theme template will get a `$form` variable.

Keep in mind that, except in a case, themes don't define forms; that is the task for a module. Eventually, themes can alter a form provided by a module, but (generally speaking) you will never see a theme that defines a form that is not for its own settings.

Comment: I was trying to follow http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-a-use-a-template-file-to-theme-a-form

Comment: I am confused  - how does function studiga_theme_preprocess_add_property_form know which tpl.php to use?

Comment: It's not the function that knows which template file to use; it's Drupal that calls that preprocess function for a theme / template named add_property_form. See node.tpl.php for which Drupal calls a preprocess function like `mymodule_preprocess_node()` o `mytheme_preprocess_node()`, where mymodule and mytheme are respectively an enabled module and a theme.

Comment: In that case, `hook_theme()` contains an entry for custom_donate_form too. Then, it has not been explicitly said, but that `custom_donate_form()` is an example of module code. A theme can just define its settings form, not any other form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your theme name(studiga_theme) is wrong. Try making it just "studiga". "_theme" is reserved word in Drupal. I also faced similar issue once.  Hope that will resolve your problem.

Comment: The short name of the theme is not a problem, if the theme doesn't define a `studiga_theme()` function, and there isn't a studiga module. Otherwise, `studiga_theme()` would be understood from Drupal as `hook_theme()` implementation of the studiga module.

Comment: The name of the theme is studiga_theme

Comment: I know. As I said, that would be a problem only in a case. That is not the reason of the issue the OP is having, though.

Comment: function studiga_theme_preprocess_add_property_form(&$variables) { 
  $form = $variables['form']; 
  $form['first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('First name')),
    );        
    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        and   <?php print render($form['first_name']); ?> in the tpl.php but no input field shows up